# What is the difference between arrayadapter and recyclerview.adapter?

Tags: android

I encountered two adapter declarations :

1. public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< Word >
2. public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder >

Both are performing almost the same job.
How are they both different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one is made for the ListView , second one is made for RecyclerView , ListView is older , and almost is replaced by RecyclerView recently , google them

Comment: What my point is, we can recycle views using a ListView and a custom ArrayAdapter. Then why go for a RecyclerView? How is it any better? I tried searching for it, but couldn't find a satisfactory explanation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is no major difference unless you want to customize a listview in a low level

Comment: feel free which ever fits your needs better

Comment: Actually, I want to customize the list items. Which one should I go for?

Comment: if you are new to android , i strongly recomend you to start with ListView, since it has more readable and easier methods , you always can customize your views in both , even easier in listview , the recyclerview is just a newer and more complicated version of listview which just makes implementing stuff like StickyHeader easier